# Add node CCK fields to a lightbox image?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a view with different nodes and an image with lightbox functionality.

I need to add some CCK fields of the node to the lightbox overlay. In other words, I don't want only the image to be displayed in the lightbox, but also some CCK fields of the current node.

What's the easiest way to do it ? Should I code it, or is there any module to customize lightbox ?

ps. My node is an Ubercart product. I also have Price, Order button, not only CCK fields.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by using the lightmodal option to include any html code and using "custom formatters" module to assign it to each image.

Successively I've edited my node.tmp.php file for being displayed in the lightbox.